# How to hide year of format using @Html.DisplayNameFor?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I need to hide my Birth date from `@Html.DisplayNameFor`.

When I view Birthdate data from the database, it shows me all of that like "2020-11-08", so  I want it to hide like "****-11-08" like that. Is this available to change format?

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Dob) // Format "****-11-08"
```

Comment: I would highly recommend doing this in the front end over the database e,g, `.ToString('****-MM-yyyy')`?

Answer (score 0):

T-SQL has a CONVERT function that can convert a datetime to a string.  See "CAST and CONVERT".  The style 23 is for yyyy-mm-dd is close to what you want.  Keep the right 6 characters.

```
select getdate() as [datetime], 
    '****' + RIGHT(CONVERT(char(10), getdate(), 23), 6) as [formatted]

datetime                formatted
----------------------- ----------
2020-11-23 14:42:03.457 ****-11-23
```

Formatting is normally for the application.  However, if there is a requirement not to transmit the full birthdate, then you have no choice.  (I would not send the full SSN only to display the last 4 digits if the requirement was never to send the full SSN.)